# Installing QGIS on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, osx

How do I get QGIS (any stable basic version) on my old Mac (OS X 10.6)?

I'm completely new with QGIS and all the instructions that I can find beats me.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [link](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/mac.php) to a QGIS 2.0 Workshop on how to Install QGIS on Mac OS X.

It will give you instructions on how to install a new version of QGIS (latest one) with all dependencies.

Initially, it will also lead you to the place where you can download a compatible version.